# Parallelizing base case calculations for recursion using OpenMP

Tags: c, recursion, openmp

I'm trying to learn the concepts OpenMP and stumbled upon a case which I'm having a hard time grasping on how to solve using this library.

Let's say we have the following recursion function

```
// ...
void recurse(int tmp[], int p, const int size)
{
   if (p == size)
   {
      // Computationally heavy, should be executed in its own "thread"
      performTask(tmp); // Note: Only requires read access
   }
   else
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
         // Alter tmp and continue recursion
         tmp[p] = i;
         recurse(tmp, p+1, size);
      }
   }
}
// ...
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int tmp[10];
    recurse(tmp, 0, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I execute `performTask` in parallel while generating new structs in the master thread using OpenMP?

I know there is something called 'tasks', and I think that's what I'm supposed to be using here, but everything I come up with just doesn't get any performance gains at all. Please point me in the right direction.

*Edit:* I made the example program more concrete for better explanation.

Comment: You have to give a little more information.  What is appendStuffOn doing?  If it is accessing a common structure, then you may not be able to gain performance because the structure might have to be locked and the overhead of locking and unlocking on the structure along with essentially serializing the code through this subrotuine might well make the preformance worse than running in serial.

Comment: By using [single](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#SINGLE), perhaps?

Comment: appendStuffOn would return a new copy of tmp.

Comment: The main thing is that the recursive function is the only one altering the structure, performTask is merely reading it.

Comment: I meant this as a comment - not an answer. The next question is when is isDone true? If you are doing all the appendStuffOn calls before performTask is even being called, then parallelization isn't going to help.

Comment: The entire structure is essentially two parts: one is generating the input structure, which is a really simple and fast method (appendStuffOn) the performTask is a very computationally heavy method. If it could branch off into it's own thread so the master thread can continue production of input values performance should improve, shouldn't it?

Comment: You didn't answer the question.  Usually a "done" flag is set when the structure is completely built - in which case you wouldn't have overlapping work and parallel would be of no help.  On the other hand, if performTask is really being done for multiple tmp structures being built, then parallel could possibly be used for some benefit.

Comment: I changed most of the program, switching the structure for an int-array instead. Should make things a bit clearer.

Comment: Sorry - but I don't see what you are trying to do.  As written performTask is only going to be executed once, when p == size and this is only going to happen after the array is filled.  I don't see any parallelism.  Now if you were going to execute perfromTask for each new element of the array, then I could see where you could parallelize what you are doing.

Comment: @ejd: the algorithm is an exhaustive search the `performTask()` is called `size**size` for example for size=4 it is called `4**4==256` times.

Comment: I have no excuse for missing this one - except too many things going on.  Thank you Sebastian!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below doesn't work as is, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction:

```
// ...
void recurse(int tmp[], int p, const int size)
{
   if (p == size)
   {
      // Computationally heavy, should be executed in its own "thread"
      // perform task using the thread pool
#pragma omp task     
      performTask(tmp); // Note: Only requires read access
   }
   else
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
         // Alter tmp and continue recursion
         tmp[p] = i;
         recurse(tmp, p+1, size);
      }
   }
}
// ...
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{    
    int tmp[10];
    // start threads
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // use single thread to construct `tmp` values
#pragma omp single nowait
    recurse(tmp, 0, 10);
}
    return 0;
}
```

The code is based on [Comparing Nested Parallel Regions and Tasking in OpenMP 3.0](http://wikis.sun.com/display/openmp/Tasks+vs+Nested+Parallel+Regions).

Comment: Your general structure is correct.  However, it will not work, because tmp is a pointer and not the array itself.  When p == size you need to make a copy of the array to pass to the function performTask.  It can be a local array declared in the block, but then you will need a taskwait after the call to performTask to make sure it doesn't go out of scope before the task is executed.

Comment: @ejd: `int` array is just a placeholder. The first OP's edit uses `StructBeingBuiltOn`. The structure is being read/written by several threads and `performTask()` expects `tmp` to be readonly so of cause the copy is necessary. `omp task firstprivate(copiable)` could be used instead of `taskwait` due to `performTask()` requires only read access.

Comment: @sebastian: firstprivate will not work because it will make a copy of the pointer and not the array

Comment: @ejd: Note that I've used `copiable` and not `tmp` on purpose. It stands for an object with a value semantics such as `struct` or `vector` (as opposed to the reference semantics of the array).

Comment: I was commenting on the code above - which will not work correctly as posted.  Your executable example is better, but still not correct.  You should also make size firstprivate on the task.

Comment: Actually your code is quite interesting.  It points out a problem with the OpenMP spec.  It also works under only one of the three compilers I tried, getting either incorrect results, or a segmentation fault at run-time.

Comment: @ejd: It sounds mysterious. What problem with the OpenMP spec are you talking? I've updated the code to be more aligned with the answer. https://gist.github.com/0fd9fd2ea7edc8e9e8c1